# Combining to JS codes, not sure I am getting the needed variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I finally understood how to loop through a JSON result and display in a DIV, but now I'm trying to add it to a jquery code that autocompletes a search suggestion.

http://jsfiddle.net/9fztL/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tagsArray = []

    $.getJSON("https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/cards?color=red&color=blue&rarity=rare&name=fire", function (result) {
        $.each(result, function (i, field) {
            //$("div").append(field.name + "<br>" + field.url + "<br> " + field.id + "<br> " + field.set_url + "<br>");
            tagsArray.push(field.name);
        });

        $(function () {
            var availableTags = tagsArray;
            $("#tags").autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });
        });
    });
});

$(function () {
    var availableTags = tagsArray;
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks like we're wrapping code in `$(function () {...})` without really understanding why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rule of thumb : keep it simple, don't use $(function(){}); or other fancy things if you don't really understand about them.

Made a quick fix for you here. http://jsfiddle.net/9fztL/4/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tagsArray = []

    $.getJSON("https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/cards?color=red&color=blue&rarity=rare&name=fire",function(result){
      $.each(result, function(i, field){
        $("div").append(field.name + "<br>" + field.url + "<br> "+ field.id + "<br> "+ field.set_url + "<br>");
        tagsArray.push(field.name);
      });

        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
          source: tagsArray
        });  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `$(function() {});` creates a [closure](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml) that takes it out of scope of your `tagsArray` variable. Your best bet would be to get rid of that in your top section like this:

```
$.getJSON("", function (result) {
    $.each(result, function () {}); // Same as you have it

    $('#tags').autocomplete({
        source: tagsArray
    });
});
```

You wouldn't need your lower section for that.